# Scraping ASPX form with Python's mechanize

Tags: python, asp.net, mechanize

Yesterday, I was trying to scrape data from [this webpage](https://servicioselectronicos.sanidadmadrid.org/LEQ/Consulta.aspx) (an interface to the number of people in waiting lists in several hospitals in Madrid, Spain). The form is pretty simple: one selects the hospital and then the form is populated with the different services (dermatology, endocrinology, etc) and the date (currently, only December 2016).

I was reading through the HTML code and tried to code a very simple Python script to accomplish the task of downloading all the data automatically. The full code is [in this github repository](https://github.com/rinze/listas_espera_scraper), but I am going to present it here step-by-step.

First, I load the page and get a reference to the main form:

```python
import mechanize

# Config vars
URL = "https://servicioselectronicos.sanidadmadrid.org/LEQ/Consulta.aspx"

if __name__ == "__main__":

    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.open(URL)
    response = br.response()
    br.select_form('aspnetForm')
    form = br.form
```

At this point, `form` contains a reference to the main form in the document. I then select the second hospital of the list (could have been any) and submit it (the original code does a `_doPostBack` to fill in the rest of the drop-down items):

```python
# Select the second hospital and re-submit in order to have the list of
# services available in that hospital
form.controls[2].items[1].selected = True
request = br.submit()
# We can now submit with the desired selection
br.select_form('aspnetForm')
form = br.form
```

Now, `form` is a reference to the filled-in form, with the list of services available for that particular hospital and the date. I then select several of these fields and re-submit:

```python
form.controls[2].items[1].selected = True
form.controls[3].items[1].selected = True
form.controls[4].items[0].selected = True
req_data = form.click_request_data()
response = br.submit()
```

**However**, and this is were I get really confused, `response` does not contain the desired result (the number of people in waiting list). The HTML code only contains the filled-in form, with the values I have selected, but nothing else.

I know this can be scrapped. I have seen another solution, written in R, that uses selenium as the browser engine. Am I missing something, or is this particular example something that cannot be scraped simply using `mechanize`, but somehow needs something a bit more complex?

Comment: you need to click the right button that will be passed as form data... not submit the form directly :-)

Comment: So, does that mean that I should include the button id code in the `br.submit()` call?

Comment: when you do directly the form submit, it doesn't send in the  post the value of your submit button. Usually ASP applications relays on those values to process events in the code. So if you are mimicking the user interface you should have something like submitbtn.click(); that will submit the form with the right data to post.